# MongoDB / Mongoose search all fields including arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to access to all fields of my model below:

```
CVSchema = new Schema({
    name : {type:String,required:true},
    fonction:{type:String,required:true},
    agence:{type:String,required:true},
    skills:[{type:String, ref:'Skill'}],
    experiences:[{
        agence:{type:String,required:true},
        client:{type:String,required:true},
        function:{type:String,required:true},
        objectif:{type:String,required:true},
        missions:[{mission:{type:String,required:true}}],
        environements:[{type:String, ref:'Skill'}]
    }]
}
```

Now, i'm using this to get the properties

```
for (var property in CV.schema.paths){
    if (CV.schema.paths.hasOwnProperty(property) && CV.schema.paths[property]["instance"] === "String") {
     //my stuff here...
            }
        }
```

But the problem is the var property return only the String and so : name,  function and agence and I would like also all String contain in the skills array or the String contain in the Experience.environements array

Hopefully you know what I mean.

I tried some code but it didn't work :(

Comment: Why are you trying to search the fields of this model? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Hi,  it's probably not the most beautifull way to do it, but i wanna make a search engine that can accept barely everything in output. So for each input i send, i wanna loop my fields.

Comment: Have you looked at using [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) with a [wildcard text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes)?

Comment: No, i didn't. i should get into this way... but i actually found an another way ton accomplish what i wanna do. Thanks man ;)